# Decimation function implemented in standard C

Tags: filters, downsampling, c

I'm thinking in a decimation C function. The prototype of the function is:

```
decimate(int N, float input[], float r, float output[])
```

where N is the length of array input and r is the reduction factor of sampling rate.

Is there a simpler way that [decimation (matlab function)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/decimate.html) to implement a decimation fuction?

Somebody knows an Open Source C library for this porpouse?

Thanks.

Comment: as a matter of fact, technology specific questions are rarely answered here, if not being closed already... In addition, however, your question looks like an order for a complete solution, which is always rejected always...

Comment: I'm sorry. The question was edited.

Comment: ok. there is an open source MATLAB clone called gnu OCTAVE. I hope/assume you can find implementation details for its dsp functions which inlcude many standard MATLAB functions including those resamplers as well... Take a look at its page.

Comment: if you want to get someone to write code for you, they might want to be paid to do it.  if you want to know what it is you need to learn, i might suggest *"polyphase FIR interpolation"*.  which can be used for either upsampling or downsampling.  if your required quality is not required to be high, perhaps *"cubic Hermite spline interpolation"* can be used instead of polyphase FIR.  since you're downsampling, you may need to low-pass filter the data before decimation to prevent aliasing.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to both. Additionally I'm going to read "Programs for Digital Signal Processing" of IEEE. (Reference of Matlab function.)